# SQL The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

Firstly I want to point, that I'm newbe in that.

I have some problem with insert into table.
When i try to run whole code at once, it gives me error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 134 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Zwierze__Klatka___440B1D61". The
>   conflict occurred in database "zoo2", table "dbo.Klatka", column
>   'ID_Klatka'.

What I tried:

1. First create all tables, after that insert.
2. To change the order of lines in query, but it doesn't help
3. To search duplicates, but with no effect.

I'm trying for about 3 hours and I don't have any idea what to do.
I know, that error is really simple to understand, but even that I don't know what to do.

You can find whole code below.

Please help me with that.

Many thanks in advance.

```
USE zoo2

Create Table Domena (
ID_Domena INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Domena varchar(80) NOT NULL,
)
Create Table Krolestwo (
ID_Krolestwo INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Krolestwo varchar(80) NOT NULL,
ID_Domena INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Domena(ID_Domena)
)
Create Table Typ (
ID_Typ INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Typ varchar(80) NOT NULL,
ID_Krolestwo INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Krolestwo(ID_Krolestwo)
)

Create Table Gromada (
ID_Gromada INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Rodzina varchar(80) NOT NULL,
ID_Typ INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Typ(ID_Typ)
)
Create Table Rzad (
ID_Rzad INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Rodzina varchar(80) NOT NULL,
ID_Gromada INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Gromada(ID_Gromada)
)
Create Table Rodzina (
ID_Rodzina INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Rodzina varchar(80) NOT NULL,
ID_Rzad INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Rzad(ID_Rzad)
)
Create Table Rodzaj (
ID_Rodzaj INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Rodzaj varchar(80) NOT NULL,
ID_Rodzina INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Rodzina(ID_Rodzina)
)

Create Table Gatunek (
ID_Gatunek INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Gatunek varchar(80) NOT NULL,
ID_Rodzaj INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Rodzaj(ID_Rodzaj),
Opis_Gatunek varchar(500)
) 

Create Table Strefa(
ID_Strefa INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Strefa char(1) NOT NULL
)

Create Table Klatka_Rozmiar(
ID_Klatka_Rozmiar INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Wysokosc INT NOT NULL,
Szerokosc INT NOT NULL,
Dlugosc INT NOT NULL
)

Create Table Pomieszczenie(
ID_Pomieszczenie INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nr_Pomieszczenie INT NOT NULL,
ID_Strefa INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Strefa(ID_Strefa)
)

Create Table Klatka (
ID_Klatka INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ID_Klatka_Rozmiar INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Klatka_Rozmiar(ID_Klatka_Rozmiar),
ID_Pomieszczenie INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Pomieszczenie(ID_Pomieszczenie),
) 

Create Table Zwierze (
ID_Zwierze INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Nazwa_Zwierze varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Klatka_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Klatka(ID_Klatka),
Zwierze_ID_Domena INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Domena(ID_Domena),
Zwierze_ID_Krolestwo INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Krolestwo(ID_Krolestwo),
Zwierze_ID_Typ INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Typ(ID_Typ),
Zwierze_ID_Gromada INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Gromada(ID_Gromada),
Zwierze_ID_Rzad INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Rzad(ID_Rzad),
Zwierze_ID_Rodzina INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Rodzina(ID_Rodzina),
Zwierze_ID_Rodzaj INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Rodzaj(ID_Rodzaj),
Zwierze_ID_Gatunek INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Gatunek(ID_Gatunek)
)

--Koniec Tworzenie Tabel--


--Dodawanie wartości--

--Dodawanie domeny--
INSERT INTO Domena
VALUES ('Eukarionty');

--Dodawanie królestwa--
INSERT INTO Krolestwo
VALUES ('Zwierzeta', 1);

--Dodawanie typu--
INSERT INTO Typ
VALUES ('Miesny', 1),('Strunowce', 1);

--Dodawanie Gromady--
INSERT INTO Gromada
VALUES ('Ssaki', 1),('Kręgowce', 2);

--Dodawanie Rzędu--
INSERT INTO Rzad
VALUES ('Parzystokopytne', 1),('Sowy', 2);

--Dodawanie Rodziny--
INSERT INTO Rodzina
VALUES ('Wołowate', 1),('Ptaki', 2);

--Dodawanie Rodzaju--
INSERT INTO Rodzaj
VALUES ('Bydło', 1),('Ptactwo', 2);

--Dodawanie Gatunku--
INSERT INTO Gatunek
VALUES ('Tur europejski', 1, '*Taki niby byk*'),('Drapieżny', 2, '*Ptak drapieżny*');

--Dodawanie Strefy--
INSERT INTO Strefa
VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C')

--Dodawanie Pomieszczenia--
INSERT INTO Pomieszczenie
VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,3)

--Dodawanie Klatek_rozmiar--
INSERT INTO Klatka_Rozmiar
VALUES (100,100,100),(500,500,500),(7000,7000,7000)

--Dodawanie Zwierząt--
INSERT INTO Zwierze
VALUES ('Byk', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 )
```

Comment: You are trying to insert a value which is not available in the referenced table.
You are trying to insert into `Zwierze` value 1 for `Klatka.ID_Klatka` which doesnt exists

Comment: Yes, as @Nilesh pointed, the error is quite iluminating. When you create tables with foreign keys, you are forcing that the keys keep constancy between tables. So, if you have a foreign key in table a with a field of table b, and you try to insert in table a a value which doesn't exists in b, you will be always receiving this error. You must do your insert statements ordered in order to avoid this issue

Comment: You never inserted anything into the table `Klatka`

Comment: Oh my god..Guys many, many thanks!
I don't know why, but yesterday after a few hours of fighting with this, I accidentally deleted whole insert table...(what i didn't notice)
I didn't expected any answer, but now, when I saw 3 answers, I was so happy.
Thank You guys!!!